# Why use a connection pool instead of a static connection variable?

Tags: java, tomcat, database-connection

Why should I prefer using a connection pool instead of static variable from a static class in Tomcat to hold the database connection?

This seems to me equivalent of using a connection pool having the capacity to store just one connection. So, a related question is: why the capacity of a connection pool needs to be bigger than one connection?

Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a pool, you can have multiple threads using different connections. Do you really want to limit your web application to handling one db-related request at a time? :) (And adding the complication of synchronizing to make sure that one thread doesn't try to use that single connection while another request is doing so...)

It would be generally a very bad idea to have a connection pool with a capacity of 1 - but at least if you did so, you could later increase the capacity without changing any other code, of course.

(EDIT: And as noted in other answers, connections in a pool can be closed and reopened if they become stale or broken in some way.)

Comment: Adding to what Jon mentioned, the single static database connection will get stale over a period of time(say if one transaction hits at 9 am and the other transaction comes in at 9 pm) and will not be usable if you try to run any query. With the static connection design, only an application server restart will be the solution in this scenario.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is to increase scalability, robustness and speed.

If you're creating a web application, there can be many concurrent HTTP requests coming in, each served by a different thread.

If you have only one static connection to the database, you need synchronization around that connection. You can't share a connection between several threads, That means each HTTP request have to wait for someone else using the database. And you need to fix up/reconnect that connection if something goes wrong with it at one point or another.

You could open a connection at the start of each HTTP request - however opening a new database connection can be expensive, and you don't get much control over how many database connections you have. Databases can be overwhelmed by having too many connections.

A connection pool solves this, as you have a pool of already opened connections that can be handed out to serve an HTTP request, or to different parts of the applications that needs to do database operations, and is returned to the pool when the database operation is finished, ready to be used again by something else.

A connection pool of just 1 connection rarely makes sense though - however connection pools take care of many other things as well, such a closing the connection and opening a new one if a connection goes stale or is otherwise in a bad state, as well as it takes care of the synchronization when there is are no more connections to hand out at a particular time.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a connection pool with only one connection it is equivalent to have one static connection - like you mentioned and there's no advantage for connection pool in regards.

The strength of a connection pool is when you're using multiple connections (multiple threads) - it saves you the effort of managing the connections (open/close connections, boilerplate-code, smart resource handling etc).

Using a connection pool for one connection only is kind of like paving a 10-lane road that will be used by one car only - lot of overhead with (almost) no gain.

Answer (score 1):

Using a connection pool is not just about sharing connections: it is about leveraging years  of experience with broken JDBC drivers and all the weird ways in which a Connection can become unusable. Using a single static connection is not only a bottleneck, but a very fragile solution. It will cause your application to break on a regular basis, and even restarting the application will not clean up the problems: you may get a connection leak.